# How to set the application as a default one?

Tags: android

I download a ics file (Outlook Calendar File) from a mail attachment in my application. Another application also downloads the ics file. I need to set my application as the default application to open the ics files (from my program). **Is there any possibility to know our application is the default application or not from our program?**

If my application is not a default application, is the user select my application at that time i have to get some details from the user.Can anyone help me to solve this???

Answer (score 1):

When the user tries to open an ICS file, the user will be prompted to open it with your app or with another app. The user will then be given the option to make the current selection the default one, so as not to be faced with the question again.

This decision should *always* be in the hands of the user.

Android has already solved this natively, and you don't have to bother with it.

Comment: I need to set my application as a default one (from my code).
If my application is not a default application, is the user select my application at that time i have to get some details from the user.So only i ask this Question !!!

Comment: @RSS: this decision should be up to the user. design your software accordingly.

Comment: Give some ideas to check the default application from code( I am new to Android)